How to binning/tokenizing amplitude of stationary timeseries?
I want to feed the amplitude of stationary timeseries into transformer.
I'm planning to tokenize/bin the amplitude into discrete value.
So, the transformer learn from unique integer token instead of continous value.
Specifically, it's an Electrocardiogram signal.
How do I do it?

This is straightforward of min-max scaling (normalization).
Except, the data is represented with unsigned integer after normalization. E.g. uint8 dtype can hold 2^8 or 256 vocabulary size.
